# How can I query with NOT IN in a many-to-many relationship including NULLs

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given I have 3 tables and I need to retrieve all the rows where there is no relationship with a specific record and include the rows where there are zero relationships, how can I build this query?

```sql
SELECT id, name FROM books;
 id | name    
---------------------------
 B1 | the book
 B2 | super book
 B3 | another great book
 B4 | how to be a book

SELECT id, name FROM authors;
 id | name         
---------------------------
 A1 | Huey
 A2 | Dewey
 A3 | Louie
 A4 | Donald

SELECT "bookId", "authorId" FROM books_authors;
 bookId | authorId           
---------------------------+---------------------------
 B1 | A1
 B3 | A2
 B4 | A2
 B4 | A4

-- Book B2 has no author
-- Book B4 has 2 authors
```

I need all books where the author Dewey (id = A2) has no relation at all.

Because B4 has a relation with author Dewey (A2), it should not be returned.

The query should return only B1 and B2.

Comment: Use `NOT EXISTS` , a lot of examples over there.

Comment: Alternatively you can `LEFT JOIN`  `authors` to `books_authors` and filter the rows that obey the condition "bookId" IS NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id 
FROM books EXCEPT (
  SELECT bookid FROM books_authors WHERE authorId='A2'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM books 
WHERE id NOT IN
(SELECT bookid FROM books_authors WHERE authorid = 'A2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Query using JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT books.* 
FROM books 
LEFT JOIN books_authors ON books_authors.bookId = books.id AND authorId <> 'A2'
WHERE authorId IS NOT NULL;
```

[PostgreSQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=5d017a400d41f0abd33c3f0e1d83e69a&php_version=null&sql_version=psql12)

Result:

```
+====+==================+
| id | name             |
+====+==================+
| B4 | how to be a book |
+----+------------------+
| B1 | the book         |
+----+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `not exists`:

```
select b.*
from books b
where not exists (select 1
                  from book_authors ba join
                       authors a
                       on ba.authorid = a.id
                  where ba.bookid = b.id and
                        a.name = 'Dewey'
                 );
```

This assumes that you want the query to refer to the author by *name* and not by the id.